# R: mclapply/pblapply vs. lapply - use case

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, mclapply

I am asking for help with this example. It might not be related to the `pbapply` package but rather to `mclapply()`. However, maybe someone has an idea whats going on here.

#### Problem

The only difference is the use of `pblapply()`/`mclapply()` instead of `lapply()` (I'm on macOS).  In this example, the `pblapply()` approach returns `NULL` while the `lapply()` attempt works just fine.

The interesting point is that it only behaves like in this example in which I use `lda()`. Other examples using `glm()` or other modelling methods work fine.

It seems that the parallel apply call does not even start here (based on how quickly it finishes).

`sperrorest()` is a generic framework (and therefore should not be the problem here) and I am confused why the example works using the sequential approach (`lapply()`) but not with the parallel one (`pblapply()`).

Also, doing the same with `foreach()` instead of using an apply* function works fine. Hence, I assume that it is unrelated to `lda()` and related to the parallel apply* call.

#### Notes:

The example runs on two cores so it should run on any machine.

First, please do `devtools::install_github("pat-s/sperrorest@mclapply-vs-lapply")`.

#### Code (reproducible)

```
library(MASS)
library(sperrorest)
library(parallel)
library(pbapply)

currentSample <- partition.cv(maipo, nfold = 4)
currentSample[[2]] <- partition.cv(maipo, nfold = 4)[[1]]
currentRes <- currentSample

lda.predfun <- function(object, newdata, fac = NULL) {
  library(nnet)
  majority <- function(x) {
    levels(x)[which.is.max(table(x))]
  }

  majority.filter <- function(x, fac) {
    for (lev in levels(fac)) {
      x[ fac == lev ] <- majority(x[ fac == lev ])
    }
    x
  }

  pred <- predict(object, newdata = newdata)$class
  if (!is.null(fac)) pred <- majority.filter(pred, newdata[,fac])
  return(pred)
}

data("maipo", package = "sperrorest")
predictors <- colnames(maipo)[5:ncol(maipo)]
fo <- as.formula(paste("croptype ~", paste(predictors, collapse = "+")))


# pblapply attempt (not working)
runreps_res <- pblapply(cl = 2, currentSample, function(X) 
  runreps(currentSample = X, data = maipo,
          formula = fo, par.mode = 1, pred.fun = lda.predfun,
          do.try = FALSE, model.fun = lda,
          error.fold = TRUE, error.rep = TRUE, do.gc = 1,
          err.train = TRUE, importance = FALSE, currentRes = currentRes, 
          pred.args = list(fac = "field"), response = "croptype", par.cl = 2, 
          coords = c("x", "y"), progress = 1, pooled.obs.train = c(), 
          pooled.obs.test = c(), err.fun = err.default))

# mclapply attempt (not working)
runreps_res <- mclapply(mc.cores = 2, currentSample, function(X) 
  runreps(currentSample = X, data = maipo,
          formula = fo, par.mode = 1, pred.fun = lda.predfun,
          do.try = FALSE, model.fun = lda,
          error.fold = TRUE, error.rep = TRUE, do.gc = 1,
          err.train = TRUE, importance = FALSE, currentRes = currentRes, 
          pred.args = list(fac = "field"), response = "croptype", par.cl = 2, 
          coords = c("x", "y"), progress = 1, pooled.obs.train = c(), 
          pooled.obs.test = c(), err.fun = err.default))

# lapply attempt (working)
runreps_res <- lapply(currentSample, function(X) 
  runreps(currentSample = X, data = maipo,
          formula = fo, par.mode = 1, pred.fun = lda.predfun,
          do.try = FALSE, model.fun = lda,
          error.fold = TRUE, error.rep = TRUE, do.gc = 1,
          err.train = TRUE, importance = FALSE, currentRes = currentRes, 
          pred.args = list(fac = "field"), response = "croptype", par.cl = 2, 
          coords = c("x", "y"), progress = 1, pooled.obs.train = c(), 
          pooled.obs.test = c(), err.fun = err.default))
```

Comment: Works on Linux with R 3.4.0.  Make sure to retry in a fresh R session, i.e. `R --vanilla`.  FYI, if you look at the code for `pblapply()` you'll see that it internally calls `mclapply()` when you use `cl = 2`.  In other words, troubleshooting `pblapply()` is the same as troubleshooting `mclapply()`.   Alternatively, see if it works with `future_lapply()` of the future package when you use `plan(multiprocess)`.

Comment: Hi @HenrikB thanks. It works indeed on Linux and macOS with `R --vanilla` and on Windows but crashes on normal macOS R otherwise. Now I need to think how to deal with that issue. First checking your `future_lapply()` to see if that helps on macOS. I was considering using `pbmclapply()` anyways which uses `future` in the background :)